# test a server with python scripts

Tags: python, testing, server

I have a complex application with both front end and back end. I need to make sure that everything is running all the time smoothly.

I am running several services that I need to monitor constantly like `nginx`, etc.

To test this particular service, I use a script like:

```
sudo systemctl status nettle
```

I have many of this to test the individual service and report their status. I want to build an application that monitor all these services and inform the global state of the system.
My approach would be to put asynchronous calls in a timer. Is that the right approach, or is there another clever way to achieve the same objective?